# Sass compilation error: Invalid propery name

Tags: css, sass, prepros

As the title says, it's saying I have an invalid property name on line 88. Which would be the li with margin 0. I included surrounding code too cause I didnt know if it would help or not.

The section below is also nest inside another. Let me know if you want me to post the entire sass file.

```
#sidebar
    background: #DF314D
    position: absolute
    width: 240px
    height: 100%
    left: -240px
    box-sizing: border-box
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box
    z-index: 50

    ul
        margin: 0
        padding: 0
        list-style: none

    li
        margin: 0

      a
        padding: 15px 20px
        font-size: 16px
        font-weight: 100
        color: white
        text-decoration: none
        display: block
        border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D
        -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out
        -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out
        -ms-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out
        -o-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out
        transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out

    &:hover a
        background: #C9223D
```

EDIT: If I delete the a section, it compiles. But I've tried deleleting all its rules and cant narrow it down to a particular one.

EDIT 2: I looked at the other post. I don't see anywhere in my code that has inconsistent indentation.

Comment: Yes, your code has inconsistent indentation.  Hint: sometimes error messages are off by one line

Comment: Slightly less cryptic translation: look at the `a` selector right below your `li`. That looks like it's over too far to me.